# Function with TypeScript works with VScode but not work with the interface of executeprogram.com

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a exercice "Quiz: Add or subtract with union" of https://www.executeprogram.com/courses/typescript-basics

> "Write a function that adds 1, subtracts 1, or does nothing to a
> number. Argument 1 is the number. Argument 2 is 'add', 'subtract', or
> 'leave-alone'"

My solution which works on Visual Studio Code :

```
 function addOrSubtract(
  number: number,
  choice: "add" | "subtract" | "leave-alone"
) {
  if (choice === "add") {
    return number + 1;
  }
  if (choice === "subtract") {
    return number - 1;
  }
  if (choice === "leave-alone") {
    return number;
  }
}

addOrSubtract(5, "add"); //6
addOrSubtract(5, "subtract"); //4
addOrSubtract(5, "leave-alone"); //5
```

But it doesn't work on interface executeprogram.com

I have 3 errors :

> addOrSubtract(5, 'add'); Expected: 6 but got: type error: Not all code
> paths return a value.
>
> addOrSubtract(5, 'subtract'); Expected: 4 but got: type error: Not all
> code paths return a value.
>
> addOrSubtract(5, 'leave-alone'); Expected: 5 but got: type error: Not
> all code paths return a value.

On VSCode it works, I don't understand what is the problem ???

Answer (score 1):

executeprogram.com has the [`noImplicitReturns`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitReturns%60) setting turned on, but your local project in VSCode does not. Add that to your `tsconfig.json` in your local project and it should be flagged as a problem.

Or [see this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoPICcDKIBGUWy0AFAFCKJggC2+AplgFzV2NYA0liEAFnBgQGrAERpUoxAB9EogM4EiJKFNmiANg2QA3BgFpkGhA1HkAlIgDePGMESl+g4YgC87uRNGWbVKlgYoECwkGnomRABqRABGAG4eAF9be0cBIQY3DwUlYmhvax5-QODQ9gj9WISqZKo7BycMrNc5LV0DIxMC3z8AoJC2cKxqxGTk8glsPEI8qFIYzk90bzjEAHo1gCYJ9CnclXnFnJmVFfW1gAYdzFx9sgXW7T1DYzBTc1WNmKA)

---

To fix it you need make absolutely sure that a `return` statement is hit. And Typescript is having a hard time knowing that you have every case covered.

Since you have three separate `if` statements here, the compiler looks at each one and says "maybe this returns, maybe it doesn't". It does that three times and concludes that maybe no return statements are hit.

---

The simplest fix is to fall through the last case:

```
function addOrSubtract(
  number: number,
  choice: "add" | "subtract" | "leave-alone"
) {
  if (choice === "add") {
    return number + 1;
  }
  if (choice === "subtract") {
    return number - 1;
  }
  
  return number; // not called conditionally
}
```

Here the compiler can see that a `return` statement will always be hit, not matter what.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoPICcDKIBGUWy0AFAFCKJggC2+AplgFzV2NYA0liEAFnBgQGrAERpUoxAB9EogM4EiJKFNmiANg2QA3BgFpkGhA1HkAlIgDePGMESl+g4YgC87uRNGWbVKlgYoECwkGnomRABqRABGAG4eAF9be0cBIQY3DwUlYmhvax5-QODQ9gj9WISqZKoeAKCQtnCsBOTyCWw8QjyoUhjOT3RvOMQAejGAJg70LtyVfsGcnpUR8bGABhnMXHmyAbktXQMjEzWJmKA)

---

Or you could use a `switch` statement so that the compiler can more easily see that all three possible values are handled.

```
function addOrSubtract(
  number: number,
  choice: "add" | "subtract" | "leave-alone"
) {
  switch(choice) {
    case 'add':
      return number + 1;
    
    case 'subtract':
      return number - 1;

    case 'leave-alone':
      return number;
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoPICcDKIBGUWy0AFAFCKJggC2+AplgFzV2NYA0liEAFnBgQGrAERpUoxAB9EogM4EiJKFNmiANg2QA3BgFpkGhA1HkAlIgDePeQHcYUfqX6Dhlm1SoRk8hogByCQDmHi9ELAYoECwkGnomRABqRABGMMQMnz9AxUJiaBCMqkjo2LYErER9NPIs338ArV0DIxMi8JKomLj2Jh4AX3Ih8glsPHyVUlTOOQlRcwBuRAB6FYAmUfRxpQKoadmFXZUF5bWABi3MXGOyGblmvUNjMFMl1ZXUoA)

Answer (score 0):

you had to add a return at the end of the function, VSCode is more robust

```
function addOrSubtract(
  number: number,
  choice: "add" | "subtract" | "leave-alone"
) {
  if (choice === "add") {
    return number + 1;
  }
  if (choice === "subtract") {
    return number - 1;
  }
  if (choice === "leave-alone") {
    return number;
  }
  return number //origin Not all code paths return a value
}

addOrSubtract(5, "add");
addOrSubtract(5, "subtract");
addOrSubtract(5, "leave-alone");
```